# Run migrations using db.create_all()

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, database-trigger, alembic

I needed to write my own Trigger to be able to update some search vectors in my Postgres database and alembic/ Sqlalchemy weren't able to autogenerate these.

For that I added my custom SQL into a migrations file. Using my dev machine everything works fine. But I noticed that the trigger is created when running my tests.

For testing I use purest and tox. My conftest.py creates the database like so:

```
@pytest.fixture
def db(app):
    _db.app = app

    with app.app_context():
        _db.create_all()

    Role.insert_roles()  # insert roles

    yield _db  # teardown

    _db.session.close()
    _db.drop_all()
```

But this script only creates the raw tables. What should I change, so that my custom SQL will be executed every time a new database is created?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I added the Trigger DDL like it was suggested in this question: [SQLAlchemy declarative: defining triggers and indexes (Postgres 9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929738/sqlalchemy-declarative-defining-triggers-and-indexes-postgres-9)